# is there any workaround to sign up windows azure free trial without a US SMS number?

Tags: windows, azure

I want to sign up windows azure free trial , however no china options in the dropdownlist , i

have credit card. but i don't have a US SMS number , how can i sign up without a us sms number

?

see my other question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11070631

**updated:**

i think this is not off topic , because stackoverflow is full of programmers , and this question is

related to windows azure developement .

if this is off topic , where should i ask this question ?

just for this, my account is banned to ask questions ....

please vote me up for reactive my account , or tell me how to reactive ....

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had signed up with non US number. Try writing your dialing country code before the phone number.

Comment: does not work for now , when  did you signed up ?